# WebHelper Assembly error using Visual Web Developer 2010 Web Forms

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, webforms, compiler-errors

I'm attempting to run a web application from VWD 2010 using Web Forms (Not MVC) but am getting this error message below:

```
Assembly 'WebHelper, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' uses 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
```

In my web.config file, there is this line of code below which I have tried as commented out, and left alone, but neither way makes any difference.

```
<add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
```

Any suggestions welcome.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this in the end, but how graceful it is yet to be seen.  I tried to download the 10.0.0.0 version of the Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms dll from Microsoft but I couldn't quite work out where it was saved to, and when I did, It was a word document which didn't really do much for me.

As it happens, my colleague had it on her machine, so I simply copied hers and it put in place on my machine.  Added the new reference to my project.  Problem solved.